# Carregamento sob demanda personalizado

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, paginação

Olá pessoal gostaria de fazer um carregamento sob demanda, mais eu não estou conseguindo montar.
Segue o meu código:

```
function show(letra) {

    var itens = "";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: 'action_search=yes&letra=' + letra,
        url: '<?= CAMINHO_ADMIN; ?>/modulos/responds.php',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.load').show();
            $('ul#alfabeto-itens').empty();
        },
        success: function (dados) {
            $('.load').hide();
            for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
                $('ul#alfabeto-itens').append('<li class="hg-services__item"><a href="<?= BASE; ?>/exames/' + dados[i].post_name + '"><span>' + dados[i].post_title + '</span></a></li>');
            }

         }
    });

}
$(function () {

    $('tr#search-indexes').on('click', 'a.letra_click', function (e) {
        var res = $(this).attr('search-letra');
        $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        show(res);
    });

    }

});
```

Explicação do código acima:
Iniciando a função de jquery, eu tenho uma lista de botões de A-Z, quando eu clico em uma letra, eu retorno em json via ajax, tudo que for igual a letra clicada. Essa requisição ajax, é realizada apartir da function "show(letra)", é nessa função que eu retorno a minha requisição php com ajax e json, bom apartir dessa função eu não consigo fazer o carregamento sob demanda, até encontrei aqui e na internet, tutoriais para carregamento sob demanda, mais não encontrei com o tipo de estrutura que eu estou fazendo.

Então, gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar com este problema, ficarei agradecido.

Att,

Alisson

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc clica num botão de uma letra, e retorna do Ajax tudo que for igual a letra... e depois disso, o que quer fazer?

Comment: Isso com certeza